# C - floor of double moduls integer

Tags: c, integer, double, floor, modulus

I need to do the following equation floor(e%100000) where e is a double. I know mod only accepts int values, how do I go about achieving this same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fmod()` function instead of `%`. It accepts `double` parameters, and returns a `double` result.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you take the floor first, then mod, ie. `floor(e) % 100000` ?

Perhaps I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. Could you give an example of the input and output you expect?

Comment: I'm converting an easting and northing in metres with a huge decimal number (converted from a lat/long) into metres and then formatting it.

Comment: This should be more or less equivalent to any other solution here.

Comment: This works only as long as the result of `floor` fits in an integer type. For extremely large floating point numbers, you need `fmod` (and need to hope it's implemented in a way that's accurate for huge numbers), but if you're using `fmod` with large numbers you're probably misusing floating point and going to run into some nasty loss-of-precision bugs.

Answer (score 3):

use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use division to make the equivalent of modulo:

```
double e = 1289401004400.589201;
const double divisor = 100000.0;
double remainder = e - floor(e / divisor) * divisor;
double result = floor(remainder);
printf("%f\n", result);
```

This prints

> 4400.000000

Of course, this is much slower than any built-in modulo...

You could also just use `fmod`, as Anders K. suggested :)

**Edit**

Fixed std::cout (C++) reference to use printf (C).  Fixed change to output.  Now it is purely C.

Comment: -1 for `cout` in a question tagged C that even says C in the subject. C is not C++.